# Insert select2 into Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have a problem trying to insert a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) into a [dropdown-menu](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns) from Bootstrap. The markup is like so:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select-box">
    <li>
        Choose categories:
        <select id="choose-category" multiple="">
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The .dropdown-select-box class in mine, for styling purposes and better control. I just can't seem to get it to work and it's driving me crazy and costing me precious time. Here is the result I wish to achieve with this:

[image: Select2 into Boostrap's dropdown-menus]

This means that the select2-container needs to be open at all times and (somehow) positioned relative to the dropdown-menu, so that the dropdown-menu can scale to the select2-container's size. I've tried to wrap my mind around this but came out empty handed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bootstrap dropdown js and select plugin js is colliding with each other...

Try remove the bootstrap dropdown js and run the code...

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script> //Remove this...
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
```

Remove all the useless js from your template...